# Fatal error: Call to a member function setMessageBody() on a non-object

Tags: error, ce-1.9.1.0

I have started to get multiple errors after updating to latest Magento 1.9.1:

> Fatal error: *Call to a member function setMessageBody()* on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/tanviherbals/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
>   on line 410

I get this error on sending data through contact us form, online consultation form, sending tracking order info, sending emails to customers from backend.

Please help on the same:

www.tanviherbals.com

Comment: Add `Mage::log($emailQueue);` just before line no. 410 in Template.php, and then check the /var/log/system.log, what's the value of $emailQueue

Answer (score 2):

just change this

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

to

```
if (false) {
```

work for order, and register

thanks.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, though...it just forces order and registration emails to not use the new queue system that was released in 1.9.1

Comment: This may alleviate the symptom but not the root cause of the problem.  The root cause is the failure of the setMessageBody() function call.  This "solution" only removes the tests & use of the new Email Queue object.  In CE 1.9.1+ Magento no longer sends order emails in a synchronous manner - it queues them up in a database table and a cron job runs every minute to process the queue & send mail.  This masks the underlying problem of your currently misconfigured system and is no guarantee that other email functions will work properly now or post-upgrades.  Solve the problem, don't cover it up.